# How can I get the python pubsub tutorial up and running?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am going through this, what should be a simple/straightforward [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-py-mac) on the GCP website, to get started on PubSub. I am working on 10.14.5, using the python environment as suggested by the tutorial. Below is the code for `pub.py`. (Code for and `sub.py` are identical to that in the tutorial.)

**pub.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# [START pubsub_quickstart_pub_all]
import argparse,os
import time
# [START pubsub_quickstart_pub_deps]
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
# [END pubsub_quickstart_pub_deps]


def get_callback(api_future, data):
    """Wrap message data in the context of the callback function."""

    def callback(api_future):
        try:
            print("Published message {} now has message ID {}".format(
                data, api_future.result()))
        except Exception:
            print("A problem occurred when publishing {}: {}\n".format(
                data, api_future.exception()))
            raise
    return callback


def pub(project_id, topic_name):
    """Publishes a message to a Pub/Sub topic."""
    # [START pubsub_quickstart_pub_client]
    # Initialize a Publisher client
    client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    # [END pubsub_quickstart_pub_client]
    # Create a fully qualified identifier in the form of
    # `projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}`
    topic_path = client.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

    # Data sent to Cloud Pub/Sub must be a bytestring
    data = b"Hello, World!"

    # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
    api_future = client.publish(topic_path, data=data)
    api_future.add_done_callback(get_callback(api_future, data))

    print("topic path:" + topic_path)
    print("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:" + os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])
    # Keep the main thread from exiting until background message
    # is processed.
    while api_future.running():
        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
    )
    parser.add_argument('project_id', help='Google Cloud project ID')
    parser.add_argument('topic_name', help='Pub/Sub topic name')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    pub(args.project_id, args.topic_name)
# [END pubsub_quickstart_pub_all]
```

However, when I run this:

`python pub.py $PROJECT hello_topic`

script, I do not get the expected behaviour. I am expecting this command to say that a message has been published, and that the subscriber command (invoked by `python sub.py $PROJECT sub_one` on another terminal), should say that a message have been received.

Furthermore, when I run `pub.py`, and examine the console here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topic/detail/hello_topic?project=MYPROJECT

The `Publish Message Count` indicates that no messages seem to have been published by the client.

I am fairly confident the set up is ok, since:

```
$ gcloud pubsub topics list
name: projects/<MYPROJECT>/topics/hello_topic

$ gcloud pubsub topics list-subscriptions hello_topic
---
  projects/<MYPROJECT>/subscriptions/sub_two
---
  projects/<MYPROJECT>/subscriptions/sub_one
```

Also, sending messages directly using the `gcloud` utility, also gives expected results.

```
$ gcloud pubsub topics publish hello_topic --message "test message 123"
messageIds:
- '709682720030464'

$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --auto-ack one_sub
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┐
│       DATA       │    MESSAGE_ID   │ ATTRIBUTES │
├──────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ test message 123 │ 709682720030464 │            │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┘
```

I also believe that the credentials have been set up correctly, although I am unsure how to verify this.

Could someone please provide pointers on what else I should check/verify to get the expected behaviour?

Comment: Include the code for pub.py in your question. Is there any output? Does Stackdriver show anything?

Comment: What's your Python version ?

Comment: Added pub.py code. There is no output when I run it. The only logging I can see in Stackdriver is for when I created the topics/subscriptions, and I am using python3.6.2

Comment: I just replicated your case and it's working for me in cloud shell. Were else are you expecting to see the output printed?

Comment: Have you tried verifying whether or not you're in the right project? (step 4) https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-py-mac#set_up_three_terminals

Comment: Try using a service account with a higher role (e.g. owner or editor) and see how it works.